# Compress Image File Size (iPhone)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, uiimage

I have a simple iPhone app that allows the user to upload images to a server. The problem is, what if they upload a large image file. I want to limit it down to (a max of) 200 KB. I started something but it seems to crash in my `while` statement.

Here's the code:

```
NSString *jpgPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@",sqlImageUploadPathTwo];
NSString *jpgPathTwo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"./../Documents/%@",sqlImageUploadPathTwo];
NSString *yourPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:jpgPath];

NSLog(@"yourPath: %@", yourPath);

NSFileManager *man = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSDictionary *attrs = [man attributesOfItemAtPath: yourPath error: NULL];
int *result = [attrs fileSize];
NSLog(@"Here's the original size: %d", result);

NSLog(@"jpgPath: %@ // jpgPathTwo: %@", jpgPath, jpgPathTwo);

while (result > 9715) {
    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed: jpgPath];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage, 0.9)];
    [imageData writeToFile:jpgPathTwo atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"just shrunk it once.");
}

NSLog(@"SIZE AFTER SHRINK: %@", result);
```

Thanks! 
Coulton

Comment: Looks like you don't change result within the while statement, so you've got one infinite loop.

Comment: I compress it till it's under a set limit (in this example, 9715 bytes). Do I need to call `result` after the compression? Thanks!

Comment: No I mean the variable "result" is not changed within the while loop, so if it was >= 9715 initially the loop never ends and you get stack overflow crash.

Comment: So if I just call it to update the `result` in the loop after it saves, it will work?

Comment: There are a few more problems - see the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:
(also note that you declared result as int* (i.e. a pointer), instead of a number, and the condition should be >, not < (otherwise for large files it won't change them at all). And an extra counter condition is useful to avoid endless loop (basically do it 5 times and then stop doing it, regardless of the size).

```
NSFileManager *man = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSDictionary *attrs = [man attributesOfItemAtPath: yourPath error: NULL];
int result = [attrs fileSize];
int count = 0;
while (result > 9715 && count < 5) {
    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed: jpgPath];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage, 0.9)];
    [imageData writeToFile:jpgPathTwo atomically:YES];
    NSDictionary *attrs = [man attributesOfItemAtPath: jpgPathTwo error: NULL];
    result = [attrs fileSize];
    count++;
    NSLog(@"just shrunk it once.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Almost there. It crashes everytime because of this line: `UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageNamed: jpgPath];`. Is there anyway we can release it at the end of the `while` statement?

Comment: You don't need to release it, it'll be done automatically. What does it say in the console about the crash? On which iteration does it crash? Note that you should really load tempImage from jpgPathTwo, not jpgPath, otherwise it'll just start resizing from scratch each time.

Comment: I defined it, set it to nil, then used the `imagedNamed` and it worked. Thanks for your help.